# Trying to display data in the Angular client side

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, interface

I'm getting `[object Object]` when I am trying to get Street name, what's the best way to show `JSON` data in the client side.

I was able to show a street name but could not for other parts. How can I retrieve other elements?

```
//Interface 

export interface Street {
    name: string;
    color: string;
}

export interface Place {
    name: string;
    streets: Street[];
    stopLights: string[];
    similarStreets: string[];
}

// Client Side
<h2>Place List</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let place of places.places">
  <li>{{place.name}}</li>      //This works and shows the name
  <li>{{place.color}}</li>    //showing [object Object] for color

</ul>

//JSON Data 
{
  "places": [
    {
      "name": "San Jose",
      "street": [
        {
          "name": "1st Street",
          "color": "Sharkish"
        },
        {
          "name": "Santa Clara",
          "color": "49ers"
        }
     ],
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to display the "color" attribute of the Place object while it is contained in the Street object. In addition, the Place interface does not match your JSON Data because streets is plural in your interface and not in your JSON Data.

Try to correct your JSON data like this :

```
//JSON Data 
{
  "places": [
    {
      "name": "San Jose",
      "streets": [
        {
          "name": "1st Street",
          "color": "Sharkish"
        },
        {
          "name": "Santa Clara",
          "color": "49ers"
        }
     ],
  }
```

Then you can do :

```
<li *ngFor="let street of place.streets">{{ street.color }}</li>
```

to access to the color of each street in your place.

Comment: How can I acess both "name": "1st Street",
          "color": "Sharkish"

Comment: {{ street.name }}, {{ street.color }}

Answer (score 2):

use another `*ngFor` for color

```
<h2>Place List</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let place of places.places">
  <li>{{place.name}}</li>
  <li *ngFor="let street of place.street">{{street.color}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The more precise correct anwser should be: use another *ngFor for street. Also instead of "let color of place.street" should be "let street of place.streets"

Comment: @Alber Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Thank you, however can you edit your anwser because is not the full correct one

Answer (score 0):

street is another array of string. So, to access the object inside it you need to use another loop(*ngFor) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! it was very helpful! After getting hands dirty I got the solution. 
Here is another example!

```
   <div>
            <ol>
                 <li *ngFor="let item of videoList" > 
                      <div>{{item.title}}</div> 
                      <ol>
                           <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.nodes"> 
                                <div>{{subItem.title}}</div> 
                           </li>
                      </ol>
                 </li>
            </ol>
       </div>


<h2>Place List</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let place of places.places"> 
  <li>{{place.name}}</li>      //This works and shows the name
  <div *ngFor="let myStreet of place.street"> 
     <li>{{ myStreet.name }} </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```